# Meteor Accounts.createUser throws internal server error?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have been using Meteor for two weeks, I am trying to add functionality to send an email once the user account has been created. I have looked at several tutorials on the Accounts.onCreateUser() function. Here is the code below.

```
if(Meteor.isClient{
   ....some code here.....
   Accounts.createUser({
      ..... Insert some options ......
   }, function(error){
      ..... some More code here ......
   });
}

if(Meteor.isServer){
   Accounts.onCreate(function(options, user){
      ...... Do the required .......
   });
}
```

It seems like it is according to the several tutorials that I have been using.

I have tested out the code and but the onCreate for the account is always returning 'Internal server error' and I can't find out a cause for it. Is this the way that I am supposed the Accounts.onCreate() callback for the form?

Also is there a debugging functionality if so I can further track the code down?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code says `onCreate` instead of [onCreateUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_oncreateuser). Maybe that's a typo? Also make sure it is returning a `user` document. You can always add a `console.log` to test if the function is being called with the right parameters.